# django - no password set after successful registration

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a custom User registration form, from the `UserCreationForm`. When I try to register, it does register successfully, and I can see a newly created user with the username and its email. But there's no password for that user.

In the admin, the password field for that user is `No password set.`. Please correct me where I am wrong. Thank you.

forms.py:

```
from album.forms import MyRegistrationForm

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success/')
    else:
        form = MyRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling save on the superclass using `super`, use the form `MyRegistrationForm`, not its superclass `UserCreationForm`.

```
user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

Comment: That did the work, thanks! Would you please be kind enough to tell me how did that worked?

Comment: Explaining `super` is tricky, so I recommend you read about it elsewhere, but I'll try to explain briefly. When you call `super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)`, it calls the save method of `UserCreationForm`'s superclass, which is `ModelForm`. When you call `super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)`, it calls the save method of `MyRegistrationForm`'s superclass, which is `UserCreationForm`. You want the second, since it is `UserCreationForm.save()` which sets the password.

Comment: That explains a lot now. Thank you for your brief but clear explanation.